# Merging two Query Results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-mapping

I have following two Queries on Same Table and need to merge it.

```
 var Prod = this.UnitOfWork.myRepository.GetData();
 var PreProd = this.UnitOfWork.myRepository.GetData();

 var Merge = Prod.Union(PreProd);
```

But when i check results of Merge it doesn't show Union but shows following message

> Message: This method supports the LINQ to Query Result Union not
>   working Entities infrastructure and is not intended to be used
>   directly from your code

How this can be accomplished.

Comment: what's the type of your query result for Prod and PreProd? it is IQuerable?
check this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3962b925-fe1e-4b96-ade3-5cb3b4be4511/compiledquery-exception-this-method-supports-linq-to-entity-infrastructure-and-is-not-intended-to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use .AsEnumerable() to convert IQueryable to IEnumerable firstly.

```
 var Prod = this.UnitOfWork.myRepository.GetData().AsEnumerable();
 var PreProd = this.UnitOfWork.myRepository.GetData().AsEnumerable();

 var Merge = Prod.Union(PreProd);
```

Comment: `Union` is [supported by EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx) i.e. IQueryable

Comment: This Worked. Don't know why we need to convert it to IEnumerable first

Comment: I think no need to convert both to IEnumerable ,see my answer.

Comment: It supports Union IQueryable and IEnumerable, not IQueryable and IQueryable

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to EF supported [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx):

```
IQueryable<TSource> Union<TSource>(
this IQueryable<TSource> source1,
IEnumerable<TSource> source2
)
```

so try:

```
 var Prod = this.UnitOfWork.myRepository.GetData();
 var PreProd = this.UnitOfWork.myRepository.GetData();

 var Merge = Prod.Union(PreProd.AsEnumerable());
```